# Express js redirect with cookie, cookie not present

Tags: javascript, express, heroku, cookies

So I've implemented facebook login using Passport-js. I've also implemented Cookie-strategy for using good ole username/password login. 
My setup is Express-js backend and a React front-end. Backend and frontend runs on different servers and domains(backend-client.com, frontend-client.com).

Everything works like a charm on localhost but not in stage and production environment. Don't know if it matters but I'm using Heroku for hosting my applications.

**The issue:**

When the facebook authentication is complete, the Express server redirects the user to the frontend app. The cookie is a JWT containing user info to check if the user is logged in.

```
const cookieSettings = {
    domain: process.env.COOKIE_DOMAIN,
    secure : (process.env.APP_MODE === 'local' ? false  : true),
    httpOnly : true,
};

const cookieMaxAge = {
    maxAge : 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 14 days, 24h, 60 min, 60 sec * miliseconds
}

router.get('/auth/facebook/', passport.authenticate('facebook'));
router.get('/auth/facebook/callback', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('facebook', async function (err, profile, info) {
        if (err || !profile) {
            res.redirect(`${process.env.FRONTEND_BASE_URL}?success=0`);
        }
        const user = await User.findOne({ facebookId : profile.facebookId });
        return user.generateAuthToken().then((token) => {
            res.cookie(COOKIE_NAME, token.token, {...cookieSettings, ...cookieMaxAge});
            res.redirect(`${process.env.FRONTEND_BASE_URL}?success=1`); // redirect back to frontend-client with cookie
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

When the user hits /auth/facebook/callback the cookie is present
[image]

However when the user returns to the frontend client no cookie is sent in the response headers.

I can't wrap my head around this. I'm I missing some fundamentals around cookies?

[image: cookie is present]

**Side note:**
When the user logs in using username and password the cookie is returned to the user. The login method is created using ajax-request with Axios if it matters. So I know there's no issue with the cookie settings I'm using.

Comment: this is really useful if you use also a graphql server like apollo or graphql-yoga. You made my day and with your snippet I solved my issue. Thanks for your useful question! ^_^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after a week or so it turns out it was a Heroku domain issue. I was using multiple Heroku domains for my frontend and backend apps(backend.herokuapp.com, frontend.herokuapp.com).

According to Heroku documentation

> In other words, in browsers that support the functionality,
>   applications in the herokuapp.com domain are prevented from setting
>   cookies for *.herokuapp.com

I solved my issue by adding a custom domain to my apps(backend.mycustomdomain.com, frontend.mycustomdomain.com) and the cookie was in added to the client from the server-response