# Cookies when using separate Dyno for react frontend and Django backend

Tags: django, heroku, cookies, cross-domain, session-cookies

I am building a simple web app using React.js for the frontend and Django for the server side.

Thus `frontend.herokuapp.com` and `backend.herokuapp.com`.

When I attempt to make calls to my API through the react app the cookie that was received from the API is not sent with the requests.

I had expected that I would be able to support this configuration without having to do anything special since all server-side requests would (I thought) be made by the JS client app directly to the backend process with their authentication cookies attached.

In an attempt to find a solution that I thought would work I attempted to set

`SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = "herokuapp.com"`

Which while less than ideal (as herokuapp.com is a vast domain) in Production would seem to be quite safe as they would then be on api.myapp.com and www.myapp.com.

However, with this value set in settings.py I get an `AuthStateMissing` when hitting my `/oauth/complete/linkedin-oauth2/` endpoint.

Searching google for `AuthStateMissing SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` yields one solitary result which implies that the issue was reported as a bug in Django social auth and has since been closed without further commentary.

Any light anyone could throw would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the exact same problem while using herokuapp.com.
I even posted a question on [SO here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54360849/express-js-redirect-with-cookie-cookie-not-present)

According to Heroku documentation:

> In other words, in browsers that support the functionality, applications in the herokuapp.com domain are prevented from setting cookies for *.herokuapp.com

Heroku blocks cookies from frontend.herokuapp.com and backend.herokuapp.com
You need to add a custom domain to frontend.herokuapp.com and backend.herokuapp.com

The entire answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54513216/1501643

Comment: I would love to buy you a drink, I would literally have never found this. If you are ever in Bermuda you should look me up, we are all in the phonebook here.

Comment: Free beer in Iceland as well.